# Erro ao salvar pedido | aplicação java web + jsp + hibernate + vraptor

Tags: java, hibernate, vraptor

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web (E-commerce), que é o trabalho final da disciplina de web, falta somente salvar o pedido no banco porém está dando um erro que não consigo resolver. Procurei, mas não consegui encontrar nada relacionado.

```
<div class="container" align="center">
    <a href="<c:url value="/pedido/pedidoFim" />" class="btn btn-success" >CONTINUAR</a><br></br>
</div>
```

Quando clico em continuar, ele está me direcionando para o método no controller que deve salvar o pedido no banco. Segue método:

```
@Path(value = { "/pedidoFim" })
public void pedidoFim() {
    Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
    pedido.setCliente(clienteLogado.getCliente());
    Date hoje = new Date();
    pedido.setDataPedido(hoje);
    pedido.setDataAlteracao(hoje);
    pedido.setSituacaoPedido(1);
    pedido.setTipoPagamento(1);
    pedido.setValorFrete(Double.parseDouble(carrinhoLogado.getValorFrete()));
    pedido.setValorTotal(Double.parseDouble(carrinhoLogado.getValorTotalPedido()));
    System.out.println(pedido);
    pedidoRepository.insert(pedido);

    for(PedidoItem itens : carrinhoLogado.getItens()){
        itens = new PedidoItem();
        itens.setPedido(pedido);
        itens.setProduto(itens.getProduto());
        itens.setQuantidade(itens.getQuantidade());
        itens.setValor(itens.getValor());
        pedidoItemRepository.insert(itens);
    }


    result.redirectTo(PedidoController.class).pedido();
}
```

Porém, está dando este erro:

```
    14:58:40,187 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-26) UT005023: Exception handling request to /LeandroMF_TrabalhoFinal/pedido/pedidoFim: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:127)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.edu.utfpr.pb.lmf.controller.PedidoController.pedidoFim(PedidoController.java:66)
    at br.edu.utfpr.pb.lmf.controller.PedidoController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.pedidoFim(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    at net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:313)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:89)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:78)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:77)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:85)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:98)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:75)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:88)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.start(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:93)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.RequestHandlerObserver.handle(RequestHandlerObserver.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:313)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:89)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:123)
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer `@Path("/pedidoFim")` ao invés de `@Path(value = { "/pedidoFim" })`?

Comment: Sim, mas ocorre o mesmo erro. E no restante do trabalho, eu utilizo o mesmo modelo @Path(value = { "-------" }) para acessar as páginas e executar o que está dentro delas

Comment: Consegui resolver estava dando esse erro por que faltou o Inject do cliente.  Obrigado.